# How can I create a Enterprise Wiki pagelayout with a repeating content type?

Tags: content-type, page-layout, enterprise-wiki

So this is the situation: my customer wants to have a web service catalog in an Enterprise Wiki. 
Per service we need to store fields like: 
 - service name
 - description
 - goal
 - status
 - version
Moreover each service has one or more operations and per operation we need to store 
 - name 
 - goal
 - logic
 - input and out parameters.
Customer wants to have a predefined layout in which he can fill the information mentioned above. I was thinking about creating a custom page layout based on the OOB Enterprise Wiki page layout. Moreover I could create a custom content type based on the OOB Enterprise Wiki Page content type. In terms of content types I might need a content type for the service definition itself containing fields such a service name, description etc. Besides I might need a content type representing a service operation. 
My questions so far are:
 - Of course I can provide the basic page-layout but it does not provide
   any suitable template for this scenario. End user has to create its
   own layout (including tables for service operations) which is error prone.
 - Let say if I have to content types (Service, ServiceOperation). As
   far as I know only one content type can be connected to one page
   layout? Is that correct?
 - How can I display repeating content types in a page layout for
   instance in a table?
 - What would be a good solution for this scenario?

Thanks in advance!